# PHP-Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have this Code for fetch data from MySql database:

```
   $sql = 'SELECT id,title,seotitle FROM ' . PROPERTIES_TABLE  . ' WHERE featured = "A" AND approved = 1 AND id = "' . safe($_GET['id']) . '" LIMIT 1';
   $r = $db->query ( $sql ) or error ('Critical Error' , mysql_error());
   $f = $db->fetcharray( $r );
  // Make all values in the array 'n/a' if empty
   $f = array_map ( 'if_empty', $f);
```

if_empty is:

```
function if_empty ( $value ) 

 { 

  if ($value == '' || $value == '0') 
   return ''; 
  else 
   return $value; 

 }
```

Now, I see this error:

```
Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\qrcode.php on line 26
```

how can i fix this ?

Comment: The query must not be finding any matching rows, so `fetcharray()` returns `false` to indicate that it has reached the end of the results.

Comment: The problem is that your `$db->fetcharray( $r )` doesn't return an array. You can simply ensure by `var_dump($f)` ing it

Comment: Is `->fetcharray()` your own method? It would be helpful to share that as well.

Comment: @Jack Yeah sure it is, it's obvious

Comment: @djay It could be part of a framework; knowing this would help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if ($f) {
    $f = array_map ( 'if_empty', $f);
}
```

Comment: It would be much better in terms of logical consequence to check if `$f` is an array rather than `0`, `false`, `empty`. So if `(is_array($f)){}` would make a bit more sense here

Comment: `fetcharray` returns an array if it successfully fetches a row, or `false` to indicate that there are no more rows. This is the logical way to test it.

Comment: If you were looping, wouldn't you write `while ($row = $db->fetcharray(r))`? My `if` is analogous to this.

Comment: @djay I'm with Barmar on this one; `$f` can only be an array or boolean `false`. If `$f` is *truthy*, it **must** be an array

Comment: @djay I hear you, but I respectfully disagree.

Comment: @Phil Since `fetcharray()` is his own method, how do you exactly know that it returns an array on success or `false` on failure? Right? We don't know that, we just simply assume that. While if `($f)` would work when `$f` even is an array, it will also work if $f is `true`, `1`, or non-empty string, while `is_array()` assures that `array_map()` will only be executed in case `$f === array` by its type. And that's the point.

Comment: I'm assuming it's just a wrapper around `mysql_fetch_array`, `mysqli_fetch_array`, or `PDO::fetch(PDO::FETCH_ARRAY)` and returns whatever they return. If you feel like being pedantic, post your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(is_array($f))   {
   $f = array_map ( 'if_empty', $f);
}
```